# How to log multiple fields in EventSource

Tags: etw-eventsource

I am using EventSource to log event. I need to record 30 fields for one event. It works if I pass all 30 fields as string one by one as shown below. I was able to log those events. But when I trying to pass a `string[]` into the `WriteEvent()`. The `isEnabled()` returns false. **Is there a better way to pass multiple fields into the `WriteEvent()` method?**

The following is my source code for my event provider.

```
sealed class NemoTraceLoggingProvider : EventSource
    {
        public static NemoTraceLoggingProvider Log = new NemoTraceLoggingProvider();

        [Event(1, Version = 12)]
        public void SendTraceLoggingEvent(string Host, string Machine, string NemoVersion, string TraceId, string Operation, string HttpResult, string CallDuration, string Segment, string InputCells,
            string InputTargetCells, string InputTargetContext, string IdentifyEntitySurfaceFormsIterations, string IdentifyEntitySurfaceFormsMaxDuration,
            string IdentifyEntitySurfaceFormsInstancesCount, string ResolveMethod2Iterations, string ResolveMethod2MaxDuration,
            string ResolveMethod2InstancesCount, string ResolveMethod3Iterations, string ResolveMethod3MaxDuration, string ResolveMethod3InstancesCount,
            string ExtractPatternIterations, string ExtractPatternMaxDuration, string ExtractPatternInstancesCount, string NormalizeTextIterations,
            string NormalizeTextMaxDuration, string NormalizeTextInstancesCount, string MaxDocumentTopics, string MaxSurfaceTopics, string MaxSurfaceWords,
            string MaxTopicWords)
        {
            if (IsEnabled())
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("TraceLogging: event is send out");
                Console.ResetColor();
                WriteEvent(1, Host, Machine, NemoVersion, TraceId, Operation, HttpResult, CallDuration, Segment, InputCells,
                            InputTargetCells, InputTargetContext, IdentifyEntitySurfaceFormsIterations, IdentifyEntitySurfaceFormsMaxDuration,
                            IdentifyEntitySurfaceFormsInstancesCount, ResolveMethod2Iterations, ResolveMethod2MaxDuration,
                            ResolveMethod2InstancesCount, ResolveMethod3Iterations, ResolveMethod3MaxDuration, ResolveMethod3InstancesCount,
                            ExtractPatternIterations, ExtractPatternMaxDuration, ExtractPatternInstancesCount, NormalizeTextIterations,
                            NormalizeTextMaxDuration, NormalizeTextInstancesCount, MaxDocumentTopics, MaxSurfaceTopics, MaxSurfaceWords,
                            MaxTopicWords);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.WriteLine("Not Enabled!!!");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: use Rich Payload: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2015/09/20/rich-payload-data-in-eventsource-v4-6/

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for letting me know this solution. It requires .NET 4.6